# Floor. Column type is not supported for List<>

Tags: flutter, floor, flutter-floor

I use the floor as SQLite abstraction in a flutter app.
The code of my entity looks like this.
`

```
@Entity(
  tableName: some_table_name,
  primaryKeys: ['identifier'],
)
class someEntity {
...
  List<String?> someList;
```

`And when I run the generator via flutter packages pub run build_runner build, I get the error:`Column type is not supported for List<String?>`

Maybe someone knows how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List<String?> is not yet supported by Floor. But you can declare it in String and when you are going to insert the list in the table, use someList.join(',')

Comment: but if my String? can contain any symbols...I think it is not the solution for my case.

Comment: Okey I understand !!! You can create an another table just for this List of String, add some_table_name primary key like a foreign key in this another table.